# NGINX start upstream error: host not found in upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

Im playing with NGINX and docker.
I try to run nginx as reverse proxy for 3 containers.

Everytime i try to start the nginx server and one of the upstream containers is not running i get the error: `[emerg] host not found in upstream "f505218f8932:8000"`

My goal is to compensate that a upstream server is down.
But when the nginx cant start if one host is down, then the whole nginx is useless.

I tried to set the DNS resolver to the docker container, without any luck.

When all upstream containers are running, my config works fine. Even i kill/stop one of the upstream servers.

The tricky part is the start phase of the nginx...

Configuration file:

```
upstream api-gateway {
    server f505218f8932:8000;
    server fcad286dab24:8000;
    server 0f1f0219dc93:8000;
}


# main server block
# this servers the frontend
# if no static file found, proxy to backend
server {

    #listen 443 ssl;
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    access_log off;
    server_tokens off;

    root /var/www/html/example.com;

    location / {

        # server static files
        # if no static file is found
        # us the backend location
        try_files index.html $uri $uri/ @backend;
        autoindex off;

    }

    location @backend {

        # use api-gateway upstream
        proxy_pass http://api-gateway;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout;

        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;

        # disable buffering
        proxy_buffering off;

        # set proxy header
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

After a long long time of debugging, if found out that docker cant resolve hostnames from container that are not running. Thats ok and fine, because the IP Adress of the container can change after startup.

So the problem is that nginx does a dns lookup on startup/reload to check if you made a typo in the config.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: But are the container hostnames needed, can't you address them by the hosts hostname or static ip?

Comment: @FrankNielsen Thats the next problem. The container IP is diffrent every time the container is started. So now im looking for a persisten IP/Hostname configuration for my upstream container. But i want that this is handled by docker itself and not via config options like `--ip` or similiar. It can be too a problem with my network. I have to dig deeper in this...

Comment: You need dynamic management of your upstream target so that only existing ones are defined. [This article](http://www.ameyalokare.com/docker/2017/09/27/nginx-dynamic-upstreams-docker.html) provides several approaches to the problem, one of them being simply using docker compose automatic round robin on service containers. You can find other resources on the same subject to get the best solution in your scenario.

Comment: @Zeitounator This approach seems to be a good solution. I want to create the upstream block anyway danamic with node.js. I tought this is something i can trick docker to do it for me... To bad nginx behaves like this. Do you know if i can execute/run/spawn `docker events ...` via the docker.sock file under `/var/run/...` ?

Comment: You can have a look at [jwilder nginx proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) for an example of this.

Comment: @Zeitounator https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/SystemEvents is what i want :) Thank you!

Comment: But if you expose each containers port, you dont need the container ip. On the host (same as the nginx server?) you just use localhost and the exposed port.

Comment: @FrankNielsen nginx is a service on docker swam. it does not run on the docker host, its a container inside a cluster.